# Python Generic functions with generic parameters

Tags: python, design-patterns, interface

I'm not sure if I used the right terms in the title. This maybe a known way to program interface functions for a subsystem or module but because I don't know the keywords, I'm not finding the results in my search queries.

I want to create a function whose intention can be clearly described in the functions name but the parameters are flexible. I want to write the function to be generic enough so that the function can complete the intention with whatever parameters it receives from whichever caller.

Let's take a function `do_foo`.
`do_foo` can take in `some_obj` whose attributes allows `do_foo` to do its work. Additionally, `do_foo` can just take in the individual attributes it cares about like `obj_attr0` or `obj_attr1` and perform the same work. In both cases, the expected result is the same as well.

So this would look something like this:

```
Class SomeObj(): 
   def __init__(self, obj_attr0, obj_attr1, obj_attrN):
     self.obj_attr0 = None
     self.obj_attr1 = None
     self.obj_attrN = None # denotes an N number of attributes

def do_foo(params)
   # unpack params. do_foo requires obj_attr0 and obj_attr1 and so its searching it in the params iterable
   # determine which data is passed in 
   # execute the work the same way regardless of what form the data is passed in
   pass

obj_attr0 = None
obj_attr1 = None
obj_attrN = None
some_obj = SomeObj(obj_attr0, obj_attr1, obj_attrN)
# One can either call with a subset of attributes that would make up SomeObj or SomeObj itself if all the information is there. E.g.:

params = (some_obj)
do_foo(params)

# OR

params = (obj_att0, obj_attr1)
do_foo(params)
```

I know python offers *args and **kwargs facilities that offer the flexibility above. I'm looking for some examples of where the implementation lends itself to reducing pitfalls. What is a good way to implement the above? And if there are any resources out there what are examples/articles/or terms that describe the above style of programming? Clearly, I'm trying to write my interface functions to be generic and usable in multiple logic paths where the users has its data in different forms where sticking to a specific parameter list is limiting.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

You can use function decorators to do this

### Long answer:

I have a concrete example for you. It might not be the prettiest code but it does something similar to what you are asking for.

## Mini HTTP Testing library

I made a mini HTTP testing library because I make my REST http tests in python, and I realized that I always write the same code again and again. So I made a more general setup

### The core

The core is kind of ugly and this is the part I don't want to write again and again.

Just skip this part quick and check how it is used in the interface section.

Then if you like it you can go back and try to understand how it is all tied together.

```py
# base.py
import json, requests, inspect

# This function drops invallid parameters
def request(*args, **kwargs):
    allowed = inspect.signature(requests.Session.request).parameters
    return {k:v for (k,v) in kwargs.items() if k in allowed}


def response(r, code):
    if r.status_code != code:
        print(r.text)
        return
    data = r.json()
    if data: 
        print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
        return data

# This is the core function it is not pretty but it creates all the abstaction in multiple levels of decorations.
def HTTP(base_url):
    def outer(func_one):
        def over(*args_one, **kwargs_one):
            req, url, code = func_one(*args_one, **kwargs_one)
            url = base_url + url
            def inner(func_two):
                def under(*args_two, **kwargs_two):
                    allowed = inspect.signature(func_two).parameters
                    kwparams = {k:v for (k,v) in kwargs_two.items() if k in allowed}
                    from_inner = func_two(*args_two, **kwparams)
                    u = url.format(id=kwargs_two.pop('_id')) if '{id}' in url else url
                    r = req(u, **request(**kwargs_two, **from_inner))
                    return response(r, code)
                return under
            return inner
        return over
    return outer
```

### The interface

The interface functions are all each decorated by the `HTTP` function which makes them a HTTP caller function, it is still abstract since it will return a function.

*Note: interface is just what I call it but it is really just functions which returns functions based on the HTTP decorator*

```py
BASE_URL = "https://example.com"

@HTTP(BASE_URL)
def POST(url, code=200): return requests.post, url, code

@HTTP(BASE_URL)
def PUT(url, code=200): return requests.put, url, code

@HTTP(BASE_URL)
def DELETE(url, code=200): return requests.delete, url, code

@HTTP(BASE_URL)
def GET(url, code=200): return requests.get, url, code
```

#### A middleware function

When one of the interface functions are decorated with this one then they need a token.

```py
def AUTH(func):
    def inner(token, *args, **kwargs):
        headers  = {'Authorization': f'bearer {token}'}
        return func(*args, **kwargs, headers=headers)
    return inner
```

### The implementation

The interface can be used for many implementations.

Here I use the interface of POST, PUT, GET and DELETE for the user model.

This is the final decoration, and the functions returned will actually return content instead of other functions.

```py
# users.py
from httplib.base import (
        POST,
        GET,
        DELETE, 
        PUT, 
        AUTH, 
        request
        )

@POST('/users',200)
def insert(user): 
    return request(json=user)


@AUTH
@GET('/users')
def find(_filter={}): 
    return request(params=_filter)


@AUTH
@GET('/users/{id}')
def find_one(_id): 
    return request()


@AUTH
@DELETE('/users/{id}')
def delete(_id): 
    return request()


@AUTH
@PUT('/users/{id}')
def update(_id, updates={}): 
    return request(json=updates)
```

### Operation

Here you can see how the users delete insert and find functions work.

```py
from httplib import users

def create_and_delete_users(token, n): return [
    users.delete(token, _id=x['user']['id'])
    for x in [
        users.insert(user={
            'username'  : f'useruser{str(i).zfill(2)}',
            'password'  : 'secretpassword',
            'email'     : f'useruser{str(i).zfill(2)}@mail.com',
            'gender'    : 'male',
    }) for i in range(n)]
]

def find_all_and_then_find_each(token): return [
    users.find_one(token, _id=x['id'])
    for x in users.find(token)['data']
]
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand, though I don't think that takes away from its utility. How does `HTTP` decorate the interface? Its hard for me to understand how `BASE_URL` is used.